# Table not appearing in LaTex document

Tags: tables

I do want to create this table in LaTex/Overleaf. However, the table simply does not appear in the document. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Variables description}
    \label{variables_description}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
\midrule\midrule
Variable & Definition \\
\midrule
$ROE$ & Net income (loss) before taxes divided by capital and surplus of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$ROA$ & Net income (loss) before taxes divided by total assets of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$RAROE$ & Return on equity before taxes of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t} divided by the 3-year standard deviation of return on equity before taxes of insurer \textit{i} from year \textit{t-2} to year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$RAROA$ & Return on assets before taxes of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t} divided by the 3-year standard deviation of return on assets before taxes of insurer \textit{i} from year \textit{t-2} to year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$TotalAssets$ & Total assets of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t-1}. \\
\addlinespace
$GPW$ & Gross premiums written of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t-1}. \\
\addlinespace
$\Delta GPW$ & Gross premiums written of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t} divided by gross premiums written of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t-1}. \\
\addlinespace
$Solvency$ & Capital and surplus divided by total assets of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. & \\
\addlinespace
$Combined$ & Sum of the loss ratio and expense ratio of insurer \textit{i} in year  \textit{t}. Loss ratio is defined as net claims incurred divided by earned premiums. Expense ratio is defined as net operating expenses divided by net premiums written. \\
\addlinespace
$Reinsurance$ & Reinsurance ceded divided by the sum of direct premiums and reinsurance assumed of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$Liquidity$ & Liquid assets divided by total liabilities of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$Public$ & Binary variable, equal to one if insurer \textit{i} is publicly listed in year \textit{t}, and zero otherwise. \\
\addlinespace
$Group$ & Binary variable, equal to one if insurer \textit{i} is affiliated to an insurance group in year \textit{t}, and zero otherwise. \\
\midrule\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize{\textit{Note:} This table defines all variables used in this paper. The source for the data of all variables is Bureau van Dijk’s Orbis Insurance Focus database.}} \\
\end{tabularx}\\ 
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please always show a minimal working example instead of a code snippet only. And always show error messages you get. If I extend your code to compile, I get the error message:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 
                             
l.40 \end{tabularx}
```

This is because here:

```
$Solvency$ & Capital and surplus divided by total assets of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. & \\
```

you have an extra `&` before the `\\` .

Fixing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}% Because of using \caption before tabular.
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Variables description}
    \label{variables_description}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
\midrule\midrule
Variable & Definition \\
\midrule
$ROE$ & Net income (loss) before taxes divided by capital and surplus of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$ROA$ & Net income (loss) before taxes divided by total assets of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$RAROE$ & Return on equity before taxes of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t} divided by the 3-year standard deviation of return on equity before taxes of insurer \textit{i} from year \textit{t-2} to year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$RAROA$ & Return on assets before taxes of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t} divided by the 3-year standard deviation of return on assets before taxes of insurer \textit{i} from year \textit{t-2} to year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$TotalAssets$ & Total assets of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t-1}. \\
\addlinespace
$GPW$ & Gross premiums written of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t-1}. \\
\addlinespace
$\Delta GPW$ & Gross premiums written of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t} divided by gross premiums written of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t-1}. \\
\addlinespace
$Solvency$ & Capital and surplus divided by total assets of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$Combined$ & Sum of the loss ratio and expense ratio of insurer \textit{i} in year  \textit{t}. Loss ratio is defined as net claims incurred divided by earned premiums. Expense ratio is defined as net operating expenses divided by net premiums written. \\
\addlinespace
$Reinsurance$ & Reinsurance ceded divided by the sum of direct premiums and reinsurance assumed of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$Liquidity$ & Liquid assets divided by total liabilities of insurer \textit{i} in year \textit{t}. \\
\addlinespace
$Public$ & Binary variable, equal to one if insurer \textit{i} is publicly listed in year \textit{t}, and zero otherwise. \\
\addlinespace
$Group$ & Binary variable, equal to one if insurer \textit{i} is affiliated to an insurance group in year \textit{t}, and zero otherwise. \\
\midrule\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize{\textit{Note:} This table defines all variables used in this paper. The source for the data of all variables is Bureau van Dijk’s Orbis Insurance Focus database.}} \\
\end{tabularx}\\ 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

So you always should have a look at the error messages, even if Overleaf produces an output.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to removing the spurious `&` character in the "Solvency" line, you should also (a) use math mode rather than `\textit` for variables such as `t`, `t-1`, `t-2`, and `i` and (b) use either `\mathit` or `\mathrm`, but not plain math mode, for multi-letter variable names. The legend at the bottom of the table needn't be part of the `tabularx` material. Oh, and please don't generate double rules when single rules do just as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\ensuremath{\mathit{#1}}} % or "\mathrm"
\begin{document} 

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

    \caption{Variable definitions\strut}
    \label{variables_description}
    
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X @{}}
\toprule
Variable & Definition \\
\midrule

\vn{ROE} & Net income (loss) before taxes divided by capital and surplus of insurer $i$ in year~$t$. \\

\vn{ROA} & Net income (loss) before taxes divided by total assets of insurer $i$ in year~$t$. \\

\vn{RAROE} & Return on equity before taxes of insurer $i$ in year~$t$ divided by the 3-year standard deviation of return on equity before taxes of insurer $i$ from year $t-2$ to year~$t$. \\

\vn{RAROA} & Return on assets before taxes of insurer $i$ in year~$t$ divided by the 3-year standard deviation of return on assets before taxes of insurer $i$ from year $t-2$ to year~$t$. \\

\vn{TotalAssets} & Total assets of insurer $i$ in year $t-1$. \\

\vn{GPW} & Gross premiums written of insurer $i$ in year $t-1$. \\

$\Delta\vn{GPW}$ & Gross premiums written of insurer $i$ in year~$t$ divided by gross premiums written of insurer $i$ in year $t-1$. \\

\vn{Solvency} & Capital and surplus divided by total assets of insurer $i$ in year~$t$.  \\

\vn{Combined} & Sum of the loss ratio and expense ratio of insurer $i$ in year  $t$. Loss ratio is defined as net claims incurred divided by earned premiums. Expense ratio is defined as net operating expenses divided by net premiums written. \\

\vn{Reinsurance} & Reinsurance ceded divided by the sum of direct premiums and reinsurance assumed of insurer $i$ in year~$t$. \\

\vn{Liquidity} & Liquid assets divided by total liabilities of insurer $i$ in year~$t$. \\

\vn{Public} & Binary variable, equal to one if insurer $i$ is publicly listed in year~$t$, and zero otherwise. \\

\vn{Group} & Binary variable, equal to one if insurer $i$ is affiliated to an insurance group in year~$t$, and zero otherwise. \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
\textit{Note:} This table defines all variables used in this paper. 
The source for the data of all variables is Bureau van Dijk's 
Orbis Insurance Focus database. 

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use package `caption` for `\caption` on top of a tabular.

Answer (score 2):

You should always watch for errors and should read a log LaTeX produces in case of unexpected PDF or wrong result.

EDIT. There are math expressions in the second column, which I missed. It is recommended to use math mode in order to achieve the correct typesetting. For comparison, have a loot at my screenshot and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676246/31283)'s answer. You see math mode gives much improved result.

I would like to add a few suggestions on top of [cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676234/31283)'s answer, mostly for convenience. I also cut-out unnecessary parts not related to the table.

In order to avoid repeated code in each cell, you can move the formatting to to column definition. In your case that would be `>{\itshape}l` as I believe you want text in italic. If you really want cells in math mode, change the specification to `>{$}l<{$}`; requires `array` package but it is also loaded by `tabularx`. However, the first row, a header, should be unaffected. The effect can be cancelled either via `\normalfont` or `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}`.

You could change all instances of `\textit{...}` to say `\emph{...}`, which also italicises texts. Then, in case you change your mind, the style of the whole text can be changed in one place by redefining the macro in use, e.g.

```
\RenewDocumentCommand\emph{m}{\ifmmode\mathbf{#1}\else\textbf{#1}\fi}
```

If this line is added inside the table or any other environment, it would only affect the macro inside that environment (See the edit above)

The effect of multiple copies of `\addlinespace` could  be also achieved via  `\renewcommand\arraystretch{<factor>}` with a factor equal to 1.25 or so. The effect is asymmetric and more prominent the higher is `<factor>`. This is corrected in code.

Also, apart from extra `&` in one row, you have `\\` after `\end{tabularx}`. I assume it is a type.

Here's the table

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{-1pt} % Corrects asymmetric effect of arraystretch
  % \RenewDocumentCommand\emph{m}{\ifmmode\mathbf{#1}\else\textbf{#1}\fi}
  \centering
  \caption{Variables description}
  \label{variables_description}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\itshape}l X}
    \midrule\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable} & Definition \\
    \midrule
    ROE         & Net income (loss) before taxes divided by capital and surplus of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t}. \\
    ROA         & Net income (loss) before taxes divided by total assets of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t}. \\
    RAROE       & Return on equity before taxes of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t} divided by the 3-year standard deviation of return on equity before taxes of insurer \emph{i} from year \emph{t-2} to year \emph{t}. \\
    RAROA       & Return on assets before taxes of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t} divided by the 3-year standard deviation of return on assets before taxes of insurer \emph{i} from year \emph{t-2} to year \emph{t}. \\
    TotalAssets & Total assets of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t-1}. \\
    GPW         & Gross premiums written of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t-1}. \\
    $\Delta$GPW & Gross premiums written of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t} divided by gross premiums written of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t-1}. \\
    Solvency    & Capital and surplus divided by total assets of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t}. \\
    Combined    & Sum of the loss ratio and expense ratio of insurer \emph{i} in year  \emph{t}. Loss ratio is defined as net claims incurred divided by earned premiums. Expense ratio is defined as net operating expenses divided by net premiums written. \\
    Reinsurance & Reinsurance ceded divided by the sum of direct premiums and reinsurance assumed of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t}. \\
    Liquidity   & Liquid assets divided by total liabilities of insurer \emph{i} in year \emph{t}. \\
    Public      & Binary variable, equal to one if insurer \emph{i} is publicly listed in year \emph{t}, and zero otherwise. \\
    Group       & Binary variable, equal to one if insurer \emph{i} is affiliated to an insurance group in year \emph{t}, and zero otherwise. \\
    \midrule\bottomrule[\lightrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{\footnotesize{\emph{Note:} This table defines all variables used in this paper. The source for the data of all variables is Bureau van Dijk’s Orbis Insurance Focus database.}}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion, "You could change all instances of `\textit{...}` to say `\emph{...}`, which also italicises texts", misses an important point: The arguments (`i`, `t`, `t-1`, and `t-2`) should be processed in *math mode* and not in text (italic) mode. This is particularly evident in how the `-` symbol in `t-1` and `t-2` gets typeset -- as a proper math-minus symbol in math mode, but as a much too short hyphenation character in text mode.

Comment: @Mico That's a valid point. I was going to change the answer but decided to leave it as is for two reasons: you have addressed this issue in your post and OP can compare the difference of two outcomes; and my approach would still demonstrates the usage of a common macro to avoid repetition. Thanks.